# Returning to the top of the code/resetting code

Tags: c

I'm very new to coding. I am doing a task. I want my code to basically restart again if they answer `y` to do you want again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char play;
    int choice;

    printf("Welcome to Two doors.\n");
    printf("Would you like to play? (y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", &play);

    if (play == 'y')
    {
        printf("You are a prisoner in a room with 2 doors and 2 guards.\n");
        printf("One of the doors will guide you to freedom and behind the other is a hangman --you don't know which is which.\n");
        printf("One of the guards always tells the truth and the other always lies. You don't know which one is the truth-teller or the liar either.\n");
        printf("You have to choose and open one of these doors, but you can only ask a single question to one of the guards.\n");
        printf("What do you ask so you can pick the door to freedom?\n\n");
        printf("\t1. Ask the truth-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
        printf("\t2. Ask the liar-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
        printf("\t3. Doesn't matter which one you pick.\n");
        printf ("Enter a number between 1 and 3: ");
        scanf("%i" , &choice);

        char *answer = "No matter which one you choose the guards both tell you which door leads to death, and therefore you can pick the other door.\n";

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf(answer);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf(answer);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf(answer);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        printf("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%s", &play);
        if (play == 'y')
            printf(main);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Describe what exactly your problem is.

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `scanf("%s", &play);`   The variable `play` is a single character, the input format specifier `%s` tries to input a character array *and* terminates that character array with a NUL byte.  Not what you want.  Suggest: `play = getchar();`

Answer (score 2):

A good idea would be to wrap the part which should be repeated multiple times in `do {} while ()` [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_do_while_loop.htm). 
Something like this:

```
do {
    printf("You are a prisoner in a room with 2 doors and 2 guards.\n");
    printf("One of the doors will guide you to freedom and behind the other is a hangman --you don't know which is which.\n");
    printf("One of the guards always tells the truth and the other always lies. You don't know which one is the truth-teller or the liar either.\n");
    printf("You have to choose and open one of these doors, but you can only ask a single question to one of the guards.\n");
    printf("What do you ask so you can pick the door to freedom?\n\n");
    printf("\t1. Ask the truth-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
    printf("\t2. Ask the liar-guard to point to the door of doom.\n");
    printf("\t3. Doesn't matter which one you pick.\n");
    printf ("Enter a number between 1 and 3: ");
    scanf("%i" , &choice);

    char *answer = "No matter which one you choose the guards both tell you which door leads to death, and therefore you can pick the other door.\n";

    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf(answer);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf(answer);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf(answer);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    printf("Would you like to play again? (y/n): ");
    int result = getchar();
    while (result == '\n' || result == EOF) 
       result = getchar();
    }
    if (result == EOF) break;
    play = (char)result;
while (play == 'y')
```

UPD: As [user3629249](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) pointed out, the input reading in the sample from the question is incorrect. So I fixed it.

Comment: This does not fix the underlying problem with the code.  I.E.  the code is trying to input a string into a single character. (this will always fail to perform as desired)

Comment: @user3629249 : agreed and fixed